# Construction of function from given condition on function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be defined on $\mathbb R$ and Assume that there exist at least one point $x_0$ in $\mathbb R$ at which $f$ is continuous .Suppose also that for every $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$ ,$f$ satisfies following equation
 $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
Prove that $\exists a$ which is constant such that $f(x)=ax$ for all $x$
My attempt $f(0)=0$ by substitution .As $f$ is continous at $x_0$ then there exist sequnce $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x_0$ and $f(x_0)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ 
Also I can say that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ such that there is $h \in \mathbb R$ such that  $|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|h|<\delta$ 
$|f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)|=|f(h)|<\epsilon$  whenever $|h|<\delta$ 
  As $f(0)=0$ so $f$ is continuous at $0$.
For integer $m$ ,$f(m.1)=m f(1)$.
For rational point $\frac mn$.
$f(\frac mn)=mf(\frac 1n)$
$f(1)=f(m(\frac 1m))=mf(\frac 1m)$.SO $\frac {f(1)}{m}=f(\frac 1m)$
Therefore $f(\frac mn)=\frac {m}{n}f(1) $
Consider sequnce $x_n$ $\in \mathbb Q$ such that converging to $x \in \mathbb R$ so $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$=$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n f(1)$=xf(1) Done Thanks for Hint.

Comment: This is known as [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). The first step is to show that for any $q \in \Bbb Q$, $f(q)=aq$ and then use continuity at $x_0$ to expand the result to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Why did you reject Real_Galois's [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1006710)?  MathJax is [required on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22025/is-it-required-to-use-mathjax-for-simple-listings-of-numbers).

Comment: Sorry For that I was new for this .It has been done by me in Rush.Actually that edit was worth of giving.I was trying now but It was not working...I had regret me for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(0)=0
.As f is continous at $x_0$ then there exist sequnce $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x_0$ and f($x_0$)=$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ 
Also I can say that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ such that there is h $\in R$ such that  |f($x_0+h$)-f($x_0$)|<$\epsilon$ whenever |h|<$\delta$ 
|f($x_0+h$)-f($x_0$)|=|f($h$)|<$\epsilon$  whenever |h|<$\delta$ 
  As f(0)=0 so f is continuous at 0.
For integer m ,f(m.1)=m f(1).
For rational point m/n.
f(m/n)=mf(1/n)
f(1)=f(m(1/m))=mf(1/m).SO f(1)/m=f(1/m)
Therefore f(m/n)=$\frac {m}{n}$f(1) 
Consider sequnce $x_n$ $\in Q$ such that converging to x $\in R$ so f(x)=$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$=$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n f(1)$=xf(1)